# How do I assign Host Ip address to my POSTGRESQL Database

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql-9.5

I am trying to connect to PostgreSQL from python.

```
import psycopg2
import csv
import json
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="testdb", user = "postgres",  password = "postgres",host = "131.80.12.196", port = "5432")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM test;")
data = cur.fetchall()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex.py", line 4, in <module>
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database="newrelic", user = "postgres",  password = "postgres",host = "131.80.12.196", port = "5432")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "131.80.12.196" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I changed `listen_addressess ='*'` in my postgresql.cof file

I added the below lines in pg_hba.conf

```
host    all             all              0.0.0.0/0                       md5
host    all             all              ::/0                            md5
```

Here I am providing my netstat value

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Comment: Did you restart Postgres after changing `listen_addresses` ?

Comment: yes.  sudo systemctl restart postgresql.service. But still I didnot see the tcp connection opened with host ip address